# Display A Caution In Outlook Desktop App If Many Recipients On Send

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

How would I display a caution to the user in **Microsoft Outlook 365 Desktop App** when, on send email, if count of recipients is greater than, say 10, an 'Are you sure? (n/Y)' dialogue is displayed to user.

If Y, email is sent.
If N, dialogue closes.

I'm trying to solve the GDPR / data privacy problem where hundreds of recipients are added to the **Cc** line instead of **Bcc** by mistake.

The '*Large number of recipients or contact group*' MailTips feature is helpful but not working for us.

David.

Comment: Hi @David Adams, Can you achieve this with the On-send feature for outlook? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows

Using the block SendMode option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/launchevent?view=powerpoint-js-preview#available-sendmode-options

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Hmm, I never thought this would come down to a full-blown add-in, I was thinking more about some kind of rule, setting or maybe office script that all Outlook users could immediately use. That maybe the only option! Thanks for replying.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, your comment inspired me to check for existing Outlook Add-ins and I found one that fits the bill. It is far more advanced than I actually need, and obviously has a cost, but if no other option exists...